# Bootstrap 5 popover not opening

Tags: bootstrap-5, popover, bootstrap-popover

my popover doesn't work and I don't know why. It doesn't work when I get the working codes and when I write them. Please help.

Here is the code part that I want to show popover

```
                 <p
                    data-bs-container="body"
                    data-bs-toggle="popover"
                    data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-content="Top popover"
                    data-bs-trigger="hover"
                    class="d-inline-block"
                  >
                    Service Ports
                  </p>
```

Here is my imports.

```
 <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```

And this is the javascript part.

```
   var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
);
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether you have added the full code here or not but as far as what I am seeing, I can say that you are missing the `popoverTriggerList` declaration `var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call()` which might be causing the issue for you or you are not calling the js code from different file the right way. I have tried your code with the declaration and it works. Check the below code for your output:

```
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<script>
  var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
  );
  var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl);
  });
</script>
```

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
);
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-content="Top popover" data-bs-trigger="hover" class="d-inline-block">
  Service Ports
</p>
```